# Remove Certain Debug Output in terminal window

Tags: terminal, putty, javascript

I am using Putty to connect to a unix server that spits out lots of debug.

What I want to do is replace the following debug for example

```
Getting pQuality
pPtrQuality=0x588b90, len
*** 385383:47:50.283 nexus_statistics_api: NEXUS_Smartcard_Read[smartcard:LowActiveStandby] 160 msec
Getting pSignal
Getting pQuality
pPtrQuality=0x4d5880, len
Getting pSignal
Getting pQuality
pPtrQuality=0x557e30, len
Getting pSignal
Getting pQuality
pPtrQuality=0x675038, len
Getting pSignal
Getting pQuality
pPtrQuality=0x4b3f20, len
Getting pSignal
Getting pQuality
pPtrQuality=0x72b1a8, len
Getting pSignal
Getting pQuality
pPtrQuality=0x557e30, len
Getting pSignal
etc.......
```

Etc so that when this text is sent to the terminal, the terminal would not display it allow me to see Debug that I want to see, ie Javascript alerts.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you get this output when you run a certain command. You can eliminate the debug output by piping the output of the command through `grep`:

`./command 2>&1 | egrep -v 'pSignal|pQuality|pPtrQuality'`

The `2>&1` makes sure any output sent to STDERR is redirected to STDOUT before going into `grep`.